# React delay scroll onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following piece of code:

```
...
    componentDidMount() {
        const {fieldGroups, setNavigationSections, setNavigationSectionActive} = this.props;

        const filteredFieldGroups = 
            fieldGroups
                .filter(fieldGroup => fieldGroup.title)
                .map(fieldGroup => ({
                    id: fieldGroup.key,
                    title: fieldGroup.title
                }));

        if (setNavigationSections) {
            setNavigationSections(filteredFieldGroups);
        }  

        document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            sections.forEach(section => {
                if (document.getElementById(section).getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0) {
                    setNavigationSectionActive(section);
                }
            });
        });
    }
...
```

The code inside the scroll event is also run when I click on a button. Is there a way to disable/delay the 'scroll' event?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `setNavigationSectionActive()` function with a `setTimeout`?

Comment: you can take a look https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js